# Waiting for value async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

The basic premise of this is that I am trying to have a function within the class Manager wait for a value to be present before it begins. I've tried every variation of the code below and cannot seem to make it work. It does log "Special value found" so I know that it's returning the value. Why does this not work? I clearly don't understand async well.

```
async function getValue (file)  {
    let specialI = false;
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, fileContents) => {
        for (let i in data) {
            if (data[i] === GOOD) {
                specialI = true;
            }
        }

        if (specialI) {
            console.log("Special value found!");
            return data[specialI];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}

class manager() {
    async waitForSpecial() {
       let value;
       value = await getValue("file.json");
       if (value) {
           console.log("Wow it worked!");
       } else {
           console.log("Still no value...");
           await sleep(500);
           this.waitForSpecial();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from "getValue" so its immediately resolving nothing when you `await` it with `await getValue("file.json")`

Then it probably prints `Special value found!` just after it prints `Still no value`

You need to await the `fs.readFile` result as well by encapsulating the readFile invocation in a Promise like so:

```
async function getValue(file) {
    let specialI = false;
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, fileContents) => {
            for (let i in data) {
                if (data[i] === GOOD) {
                    specialI = true;
                }
            }

            if (specialI) {
                console.log("Special value found!");
                resolve(data[specialI]);
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        })
    });
}

class manager {
    async waitForSpecial() {
        let value;
        value = await getValue("file.json");
        if (value) {
            console.log("Wow it worked!");
        } else {
            console.log("Still no value...");
            await sleep(500);
            this.waitForSpecial();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution still yields the exact same output, and I have no idea as to why. I tried this earlier as well.

Comment: What's the output you're getting? Is it "Still no value..." then "Special value found!"?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that output.

Comment: @R8T3D Hm... I'm running a minimal version of the snippet I've posted (commented out the for statement; resolved a simple 'voila' if the fileContents contained the text 'test') and it works fine. The output I'm getting is "Special value found!" and "Wow it worked!" (in that order)

Comment: `for (let i in data) {` what is `data`?

Comment: `data[specialI]` ... what is `data[true]` since `specialI` is `true`

Comment: @Bravo it appears to be code that falls -mostly- outside of the scope of these two functions; for my minimally reproduced version I refactored to remove `data`, `GOOD`, and `specialI` references.

Comment: I got it, your solution works swimmingly. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's async, it will never wait for a value to proceed.
It's always better to write all the async stuff together...

If you must do it that way so I suggest you try to use a flag in a while block, although it kills the concept of async, or try to use a more accessible variable testing while it's null.